# App Script Error - Encountered an error while globbing file pattern

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-developers-console

```
function appendJoin12() {    
var datasetId = 'Join_Test';  
var tableId = 'Join12';  
var job =       

{    

configuration: 
{
  query: 
  {
    query: 'SELECT * FROM [instagram-1314:Join_Test.Join1],             
    writeDisposition:'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    destinationTable: 
    {
      projectId: 'instagram-1314',
      datasetId: 'Join_Test',
      tableId: tableId
    }  
  }     
}  
};  

var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, "instagram-1314");  
var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;  
while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {  
Utilities.sleep(1000);  
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults("instagram-1314", jobId);  
}   

Logger.log(queryResults.status);
```

};

when I am running the above code I am getting an error -

**Encountered an error while globbing file pattern**.

I enabled BigQuery Api in google developer console and also in advanced google services(App Script). Do I need to enable any other API's

Can anyone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply forgot to close the quotes on line 12. Wasn't it? otherwise it looks just like the reference

```js
function appendJoin12() {    
var datasetId = 'Join_Test';  
var tableId = 'Join12';  
var job =       

{    

configuration: 
{
  query: 
  {
    query: 'SELECT * FROM [instagram-1314:Join_Test.Join1]',             
    writeDisposition:'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    destinationTable: 
    {
      projectId: 'instagram-1314',
      datasetId: 'Join_Test',
      tableId: tableId
    }  
  }     
}  
};  

var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, "instagram-1314");  
var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;  
while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {  
Utilities.sleep(1000);  
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults("instagram-1314", jobId);  
}   

Logger.log(queryResults.status);
```

nce in the documentation